# There is no rel="next" and rel="prev" in drupal term pagas

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

How can I add rel next and previous in drupal-7 term pages programmatically? and how important is rel for google?

some of my pages are listed here:

[کاردستی](http://radiokodak.com/term/48/1)

[سوپ ساده](http://radiokodak.com/article/1416/20)

[عکس کودک](http://radiokodak.com/article/1449/180)

[کاردستی](http://radiokodak.com/article/1484/1)

[کاردستی](http://radiokodak.com/term/48/600)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there was no solution for it as a module i myself developed a module myself.
i wish it could help you

first of all we user hook_preprocess_html 
and i checked if this page is a term page or not

```
if (arg(0) == 'taxonomy' && arg(1) == 'term') {
```

and then with use of page argument and function taxonomy_select_nodes you can find on what page your are and what is the next and prevoius page
but one important this,

- First page has no previous page
- Last page has no next page
- and there is no page with argument page=1, this is the first page

  ```
  function your_theme_preprocess_html(&$variables) {

  if (arg(0) == 'taxonomy' && arg(1) == 'term') {

      $term = taxonomy_term_load(arg(2));

      if( $_GET && $_GET['page'] && is_numeric(@$_GET['page']) ){
          $prev = $_GET['page']-1;
          $next = $_GET['page']+1;
          $url = url('taxonomy/term/'.arg(2));
          if( $_GET['page'] > 1 ){
              $head_link  = array(
                  'rel' => 'prev',
                  'href' => 'http://yourdomain.com'.$url.'?page='.$prev
              );
              drupal_add_html_head_link($head_link);
          }
          if( $_GET['page'] == 1 ){
              $head_link  = array(
                  'rel' => 'prev',
                  'href' => 'http://yourdomain.com'.$url
              );
              drupal_add_html_head_link($head_link);
          }

          $numbers = taxonomy_select_nodes( arg(2),true ,1000 );
          if( count($numbers) > $next * 100 ){                
              $head_link  = array(
                  'rel' => 'next',
                  'href' => 'http://yourdomain.com'.$url.'?page='.$next
              );
              drupal_add_html_head_link($head_link);
          }

      }
      else {
          $numbers = taxonomy_select_nodes( arg(2),true ,1000 );
          if( count($numbers) > 100 ){                
              $url = url('taxonomy/term/'.arg(2));
              $head_link  = array(
                  'rel' => 'next',
                  'href' => 'http://yourdomain.com'.$url.'?page=1'
              );
              drupal_add_html_head_link($head_link);
          }
      }

  }
  }
  ```

this function taxonomy_select_nodes is really awesome, you give it "tid" of a term, it tells you how node is tagged with this term.

even you can add class to body with hook_preprocess_html

write all this code in template.php file in your theme

Comment: hi mohsen, i write this code but it says there is another function with this name.

Comment: check your template.php code there is a function named the same as your_theme_preprocess_html now your theme is magazine, there is two function named magazine_preprocess_html